# VB.net Share module code between solutions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have certain Modules that I would like to setup to be referencable by multiple solutions, as the code always behaves in basically the same manner (ex. code for logging errors). They make no sense as classes, so it seems like a class library is out; and I haven't seen any other suggestions for sharing code between solutions.

So I'm left wondering what would be the best way to create one thing that I can just use across multiple solutions to avoid having to rewrite the same code?

Comment: Right click in Solution Explorer.  Select Add Item -> Existing Item -> find file, optionally use the Add Dropdown to Add As Link.

Comment: A class library can consist of just modules if that's what you want.

Comment: @roryap I put together a Class Library with only modules. When I attempted to reference any of the functions in those modules I couldn't. Is there some different step needed to access that code? Or if I type `Dim outcome as String = MyClassLibrary.FunctionName(Var1, Var2, Var3)`, should it work?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a class library is exactly what you want. Build it, reference it within each solution, and code against it. One source, multiple solutions running off that code.

You could also implement the functionality into a separate piece such as an API. This is dependent on the function of the code obviously, but logging errors is a good use case.

Comment: 'Add as Link' is so much simpler for the OP's case.